# NGINX redirect web traffic to Netlify website

Tags: nginx, networking, reverse-proxy

I have Nginx web server that redirects traffic direct to mydomain.com between:

- A Wordpress website
- A Node API

Now I want to redirect all the traffic direct to the old Wordpress website to a new Netlify managed static website that has a URL like purple-rain.netlify.com

The main part of the config is:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    # SSH stuff managed by Certbot skipped

    # What is this for?
    root "/var/www/example/httpdocs";
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    # Redirect everything that starts with "api" or "img" to the Node API
    # like https://example.com/api/r1/users will match this

    location ~ /(api|img) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:45001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # Redirect to the same Node API (can I merge the two?)

    location ~ /js/react {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:45001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # This redirects everything that does not match to Wordpress?

    location / {
        root /var/www/example-wp/httpdocs;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # This redirects everything that ends with ".php" to Wordpress?

    location ~* \.php$ {
        root /var/www/example-wp/httpdocs;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

How do I have to change this to redirect the website traffic to the new Netlify backed website?

**EDIT with what I tried:**

I tried to redirect a single page (/work-with-us) to the netlify backed website with the `proxy_pass` directive like this:

```
location /work-with-us {
    proxy_pass https://purple-rain.netlify.com;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Before adding this I was receiving the custom 404 page from my Wordpress website correctly since I don't have this page on the old website.
After adding this I get the nginx 404 page with a "Not Found"